# Как посчитать количество вызова функции на Python?

Tags: python, функции

Есть задание:

> Напишите функцию пересчета суммы в рублях в какую-нибудь другую
> валюту. Используйте глобальную переменную в качестве счетчика
> количества вызовов функции.

Я никак что-то не могу понять, как подсчитать количество вызовов функции (о котором говорится в задании)... поможите? Вот, что у меня пока получилось:

```
rubles = float(input("Введите кол-во рублей: "))

USD = lambda rubles: rubles * 0.016
EUR = lambda rubles: rubles * 0.015
VND = lambda rubles: rubles * 385.60

print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести долларов: ", USD(rubles))
print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести евро: ", EUR(rubles))
print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести вьетнамских донгов: ", VND(rubles))
```

Comment: Замените лямбды на обычные функции, внутри этих функций увеличивайте значение глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, в общем то, и оставить лямбды, но обернуть то что они делают в функцию:

```python
rubles = float(input("Введите кол-во рублей: "))

def counter(*args, count=[0]):
    count[0]+=1
    print('Количество раз функции были вызваны: {}'.format(count[0]))
    return args[0]

USD = lambda rubles: counter(rubles * 0.016)
EUR = lambda rubles: counter(rubles * 0.015)
VND = lambda rubles: counter(rubles * 385.60)

print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести долларов: ", USD(rubles))
print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести евро: ", EUR(rubles))
print("Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести вьетнамских донгов: ", VND(rubles))
```

###### Вывод

```console
Количество раз функции были вызваны: 1
Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести долларов:  0.3232
Количество раз функции были вызваны: 2
Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести евро:  0.303
Количество раз функции были вызваны: 3
Вот сколько Вы сможете приобрести вьетнамских донгов:  7789.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное от Вас хотят чего-то подобного

```
print('введите кол-во рублей')
rubles = float(input())
cnt_calls_func = 0


def rubles_to_usd(rub):
    global cnt_calls_func
    cnt_calls_func += 1
    usd = rub * 0.016
    return f'{usd}; функцию вызвали {cnt_calls_func}'  # для склонения по падежам
    # можно воспользоваться библиотекой pymorphy2


print(rubles_to_usd(rubles))
print(rubles_to_usd(rubles))
```

Подробнее о глобальных переменных и про области видимости можно прочесть [тут](https://python-scripts.com/scope)